# How to store values in an array after performing split()?

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a txt file called fractions.txt which includes some fractions. I don't know the size of the data. I need to split the numerator and denominator and make two arrays for them. For example, 6/7 and 5/4 are in the fractions.txt. I need two arrays like a[] and b[]. Then a[0]=6, a[1]=5, b[0]=7, and b[1]=4. How to do it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;
public class Fraction2
{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;
    try{
    inputStream = new Scanner( new FileInputStream ("fractions.txt"));
    outputStream = new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream("terminal.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    String data;
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        data = inputStream.nextLine();
        String parts[] = data.split("/");

    }


    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();

}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? Please don't ask "*why my code doesn't work*" questions without being specific.

Comment: assuming one fraction per line, i.e 6/7 on first. the first iteration will give you parts[0]=6 and parts[1]=7. Now whats the issue? you can save them in any way in your terminal.txt file.

Comment: I write System.out.println(parts[0]) after the while loop and it has error.

Comment: If you try to print parts[0] outside while loop, you'll get error sure. Because parts[] has it's scope within the loop only. To print it outside the loop, declare it before the loop starts.

Comment: 'It has error' is not a problem description. Try again. Try harder.

Comment: You asked for two arrays. Arrays, however, have a fixed size, so that's why people advise you two ArrayLists. I go a bit farther: Why two array lists with each containing a different part? Try one array list containing value objects, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure of how many fractions are in the text file, I would use an `ArrayList` to store each variable.

```
// Initialize ArrayLists
ArrayList<Integer> numerators = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> denominators = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then while reading data from the text file:

```
// Store Data
numerators.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
denominators.add(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
```

With an ArrayList, you have the power to store essentially as few or as many fractions as you require.

Comment: I'd advise against this practice: You have one rational number split inbetween two lists. That doesn't fit nicely into OOP - heck, you would even make a struct in Pascal or C.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 lists

```
List<> numerators = new ArrayList<String>();
List<> denominators = new ArrayList<String>();
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
    data = inputStream.nextLine();
    String parts[] = data.split("/");
    numerators.add(parts[0]);
    denominators.add(parts[1]);
}
```

Then you can convert them to arrays if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using some value object like that:

```
class RationalNumber {
    private final int numerator;
    private final int denominator;
    // add getters and a constructor that takes both values as parameters
}
```

Then you can create instances of this type and store them in something like `ArrayList`.

```
List<RationalNumber> numbers = new ArrayList<>(); // defined outside cycle
// ...
numbers.add(new RationalNumber(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
```